# transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion view memory management?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

It doesn't seem like

```
transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:
```

Handles memory like it indicates in the Apple docs.  It is stated that the `fromView` is removed from the superview (implying a `release`) and the `toView` is added to the superview (implying a `retain`).  Is this correct?

When I transition a view, later in my app when the view is actually presented I will get a `BAD_ACCESS` as the view was deallocated.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is the code where the problem exists:

```
UIViewController *container = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
container.view.bounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
[container.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

/* Deallocated in the finish callback */
tutorialViewController = [[TutorialViewController alloc] 
                          initWithNibName:@"TutorialViewController" 
                          bundle:nil];

tutorialViewController.tutorialDelegate = self;
[tutorialViewController loadTutorialData:data];

UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
                              initWithRootViewController:tutorialViewController];
nc.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

[UIView transitionFromView:[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
                    toView:container.view
                  duration:kAnimationDuration
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                completion:nil];

[container presentModalViewController:nc animated:NO];

[container release];
[nc release];
```

If I do a `[tutorialViewController release]` at the bottom of this method, I will get the `BAD_ACCESS`.  So it seems like the UINavigationController does *not* retain the root view controller.

**P.S.**  The tutorialViewController was not a member variable previously, but I have now fixed this problem by simply releasing it after the view has been dismissed.

Comment: Can you post the code that's causing the crash?

Comment: My guess here is that using UINavigationViewController's initWithRootViewController does NOT retain the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, after much testing, is simply that `UINavigationViewController` does not retain the view with `initWithRootViewController`.  The Apple docs aren't clear on this.

Comment: Please view this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337706/need-assistance-regarding-transitionfromviewtoviewdurationoptionscompletion/16338755?noredirect=1#16338755

Answer (score 1):

You should check and confirm that you are not releasing the view yourself, hereby over-releasing. Or perhaps check the dealloc method for the view class which is being released to see if you're over-releasing anything in it.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I went through and checked and all seems to be in order.